# Search API not returning lookup column values

Tags: sharepoint-server, lookup-column, crawled-property, search-api

I want to retrieve all the library items of a content type "Prod Request". I am using REST API for this.  I am not able to get lookup column values.In below query my lookup column name is LookUp1. I am getting all column values except LookUp1. I mapped LookUp1  column to managed properties and ran a full crawl also but no use. Is there a different way for doing it in search api? Here is my query......       Please assist.

```
$.ajax({             
    url: https://mysite.domain.com/_api/search/query?querytext='contenttype:Prod Request'&rowlimit=100&trimduplicates=false&selectproperties='Title,LookUp1',
    method: "GET",
    headers: { "ACCEPT": "application/json;odata=verbose" 
},
    success: function (data) {...........
```

Some more info...
lookup column managed property is added at Site Collection administration level not at central admin level.
Full CRAWL is also performed...
I also tried modifying $expand my lookup column like below

url: "https://mysite.domain.com/_api/search/query?querytext='contenttype:Prod Request'&rowlimit=100&trimduplicates=false&selectproperties='Title,LookUp1/Title'&$expand=LookUp1",

but it didnt work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please check the points below:

1. Create the managed property in search service application level instead of site collection level. Delete site collection level property, then start a full crawl
2. Make sure the managed property is searchable, queryable and retrievable.

Comment: Thanks, adding managed property to Central admin instead of Site Collection worked...

Comment: If it helps you, you can mark it as answer. Thanks for your understanding.